# MapProxy Installation problem with PyProj

Tags: proj, windows, pyproj, mapproxy

I'm testing MapProxy (1.12.0) on a Windows Machine and followed each step from the "Installation on Windows" docs.
I have a running virtualenv, used pip to install MapProxy and PyProj.

The command `pip list` shows

```
MapProxy   1.12.0
Pillow     6.2.0
pip        19.2.3
pyproj     2.4.2.post1
PyYAML     5.1.2
setuptools 41.4.0
Shapely    1.6.4.post2
wheel      0.33.6
```

A simple `mapproxy-util --version` fails with the following traceback:

```
(mapproxy_venv) \mymapproxy>mapproxy-util --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\python\Lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "\python\Lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "\mapproxy_venv\Scripts\mapproxy-util.exe\__main__.py", line
5, in <module>
  File "\mapproxy_venv\lib\site-packages\mapproxy\script\util.py", l
ine 28, in <module>
    from mapproxy.script.conf.app import config_command
  File "\mapproxy_venv\lib\site-packages\mapproxy\script\conf\app.py
", line 32, in <module>
    from .sources import sources
  File "\mapproxy_venv\lib\site-packages\mapproxy\script\conf\source
s.py", line 17, in <module>
    from mapproxy.srs import SRS
  File "\mapproxy_venv\lib\site-packages\mapproxy\srs.py", line 26,
in <module>
    from mapproxy.proj import Proj, transform, set_datapath
  File "\mapproxy_venv\lib\site-packages\mapproxy\proj.py", line 262
, in <module>
    raise ImportError('could not find libproj or pyproj')
ImportError: could not find libproj or pyproj
```

Any ideas what went wrong? PyProj import and functions are working, tested that in the python console.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Does it work in earlier versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your pyproj is too new. I reinstalled my setup on a different computer and had to roll back all the way to pyproj 1.9.6.

I haven't dug deeper into it, but i think that pyproj has renamed something, as it is the line:

```
from pyproj import Proj, transform, set_datapath
```

that throws an exception.

After changing to pyproj 1.9.6 it works. In order to do that I also changed to python 3.7 as I'm lazy and wanted to use a precomiled package.

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the problem. MapServer should update their docs or the code...

Answer (score 2):

To add to  Stefan's answer and Baal's comment, I needed these additional commands to make proj 1.9.6 available.  (Confirming his suggestion was my issue too)  The Make and GCC stuff wasn't obvious to me when I started doing this - in case any of you attempting MapProxy are linux noobs like me :)

```
sudo pip3 install wheel
sudo pip3 install setuptools
sudo pip3 install pyyaml
sudo dnf install gcc make
sudo dnf install python3-devel
sudo pip3 install 'pyproj==1.9.6'
```

Now I get this:

```
[me@localhost ~]$ mapproxy-util --version
MapProxy 1.13.2
[me@localhost ~]$
```

One More thing:  If you are like me and testing with a headless VM, with no browsing capabilities, the binding made when doing this is to a 'localhost' host header:

```
mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml
```

This method doesn't allow someone from a different IP (my actual OS vm) access to the server.  You may need this:

```
mapproxy-util serve-develop mapproxy.yaml -b <vm-ip>:8080
```

Now it works. :)